# checking maven remote repository health status in archiva

Tags: archiva

I was using Nexus OSS. Due to issues I started using Archiva. Archiva is good. But I dont know how to check maven remote repository health status. ie whether archiva is able to connect to configured remote repository.

It is easy in Nexus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible now and I agree that could be a nice feature to have !
I don't remember if it's already recorded here http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM ?
If not you can add a jira entry for that.

### Thanks!

Olivier